# jQuery target only elements within parent div

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I have a number of widgets on a page and I want to re-use classes throughout. I have a question mark icon that should toggle visibility between 2 divs inside the widget.

The problem is I can't get my code to only target the current widget. I have tried the usual techniques but none seem to be working here.

The fiddle is here, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/9hvVn/

The click function in question works from the question mark icon. The divs that need toggleClass are .widget-content and .widget-content_next

Thanks :)

Comment: Please post the code/HTML here, not just the fiddle.  This makes SO self-contained in case other sites go down, and makes your question more searchable.  This question isn't usable without the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks guys, I went with Johan because it was the most concise solution. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

widget-content and widget-content_next aren't direct ancestors of the link, I think you want something like this:

```
 $(this).closest(".widget").find('.widget-content').toggleClass("hidden");
 $(this).closest(".widget").find(".widget-content_next").toggleClass("hidden");
```

Comment: +1; Finding the closest parent widget is a good solution for this.  Nice and flexible, yet still strict enough to ensure you stay within the widget.

Answer (score 3):

You could use parent in conjunction with siblings

```
$("a.expand_widget").live("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings(".widget-content").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(this).parent().siblings(".widget-content_next").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKMaW/

or alternatively you could limit the selector to the parent nodes

```
$("a.expand_widget").live("click", function () {
    var root = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    $(".widget-content",root).toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".widget-content_next",root).toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: +1 for the second example.  I didn't know that syntax for applying a selector only under a certain element :)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham thanks :) I've found it very useful more than once.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think [the `.closest` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) works for you because it only finds ancestors, not siblings or descendants of ancestors:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The .parents() and .closest() methods are similar in that they both traverse up the DOM tree.

#### Solution

Instead of using `.closest`, you could use [the `.parent` function](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to find the owner, then use [the other tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to find the children that [match certain selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Try this edited code - http://jsfiddle.net/9hvVn/3/:

```
$("a.expand_widget").live("click", function () {
    var parentWidget = $(this).parent('div.widget-head')
        .parent('li.widget');
    parentWidget.children(".widget-content").toggleClass("hidden");
    parentWidget.children(".widget-content_next").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

It is fairly strict, but you could loosen it up a bit if you needed to.  You could also use various sibling functions on the `div.widget-head` instead of getting the parent-of-parent first.