# target only relevant div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div structured this way:

```
<div class="sez-form ripart">
    <table class="inc_prev"></table>
    <div class="previsioni">A</div>
</div>
```

In table "inc_prev" I have a button that allows you to add another group of these. So by hitting the button you will get a structure like this:

```
<div class="sez-form ripart">
    <table class="inc_prev"></table>
    <div class="previsioni">A</div>
</div>
<div class="sez-form ripart">
    <table class="inc_prev"></table>
    <div class="previsioni">B</div>
</div>
```

Each "inc_prev" table has this html:

```
<table class="inc_prev">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><label>Mese: </label><select id="mese[]" name="mese[]"></td>
<td><label>Anno: </label><select id="anno[]" name="anno[]"></td>
<td><label>Percentuale: </label><input class="importo" type="text" name="percent[]" maxlength="14" size="15" value="">%</td>
<td><img class="addRow" src="../images/plus.png"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my JS:

```
$(document).on('blur','.importo',function(){
    var input_value = $(this).val();
    var azione =$('#azione').val();
    if ($(this).closest('.sez-form').find('.previsioni').length) {
        $('.previsioni').load('bp/ripart_prev.php?perc='+input_value+'&id='+azione);
    }else{
        console.log('qui');
        $(this).closest('.sez-form').append('<div class="previsioni"></div>');
        $('.previsioni').load('bp/ripart_prev.php?perc='+input_value+'&id='+azione);
    }
});
```

It appends the "previsioni" div if it's not there or update it loading content from DB. In the starting situation it works fine: previsioni div is added or updated in the right way. If I hit the plus button and add the second block when this JS gets triggered both the "previsioni" div get updated with the same content.
So my question is: "**how do I change my JS so that when executed only the target "previsioni" is updated?**" So if I blur the second "importo" only it's "previsioni" (B) gets updated? I am already using closest as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527483/jquery-target-only-elements-within-parent-div) but this is not preventing the other previsioni to be updated too

Comment: Thanks to all the downvoter. JS is not my cup of tea yet and sometimes I don't see the solution even if it is right in front of me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `$('.previsioni')` will select all the existing elements with the class. You need to reuse the relationship to target the specific div. Here in the code snippet I have cached the `$(this).closest('.sez-form').find('.previsioni')` in an object.

*Read inline comments*

```
$(document).on('blur','.importo',function(){
    var input_value = $(this).val();
    var azione =$('#azione').val();

    //Use the relationship again to traverse and cache it in a vraible the content
    var previsioni = $(this).closest('.sez-form').find('.previsioni');

    //If exist
    if (previsioni.length) {            
        previsioni.load('bp/ripart_prev.php?perc='+input_value+'&id='+azione)
    }else{
        console.log('qui');

        //Create div using JQuery
        var div = $('<div class="previsioni"></div>');
        //Load the content
        div.load('bp/ripart_prev.php?perc='+input_value+'&id='+azione)

        //Append the data
        $(this).closest('.sez-form').append(div);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I know I have to fix many things yet here on ids and so... this is still a work in progress reusing some pieces of code I wrote when the page was supposed to work in another way